# Setting the minimum vertical value of a column chart using the Visualization Google API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, google-visualization

I am using the Google Chart API with AngularJS.
I have tried to set the `min` property of the vertical axis of my column chart to `0` by doing this:

```js
var dataMois = CaDuMois.query(function(){
    $scope.comparatifVentes.data = {
        "cols": [
            {id: "t", label: "Mois", type: "string"},
            {id: "s", label: "Vente", type: "number"}
        ],
        "rows": [
            {c: [
                {v: d.getFullYear()-4},
                {v: dataMois[4].valeur},
            ]},
            {c: [
                {v: d.getFullYear()-3},
                {v: dataMois[3].valeur}
            ]},
            {c: [
                {v: d.getFullYear()-2},
                {v: dataMois[2].valeur},
            ]},
            {c: [
                {v: d.getFullYear()-1},
                {v: dataMois[1].valeur},
            ]},
            {c: [
                {v: "Encours "+d.getFullYear()},
                {v: dataMois[0].valeur},
            ]}
        ],
        "vAxis.viewWindow": [{min:"0"}]
    };
    $scope.comparatifVentes.type = "ColumnChart";
    $scope.comparatifVentes.options = {
        'backgroundColor': '#f5f5f5',
        'title': "Montant(€) total des ventes des 5 derniers mois de "+monthNames[n],'height':"250"
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div google-chart chart="comparatifVentes" style="{{chart.cssStyle}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the `min` is still at `250000` on my chart.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, [Visualization: Column Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart):

> **vAxis.viewWindow.min**
>
> The minimum horizontal data value to render.
>
> Ignored when vAxis.viewWindowMode is 'pretty' or 'maximized'.
> Type: number
> Default: auto

I'm guessing "horizontal" is a typo.

This should be written like this:

```
// create properly
var options = {
    vAxis : { 
        viewWindow : { 
            min : 0 
        }
    } 
}
```

Although once created, it is also accessible like this:

```
// use this to modify only if it exists already
options.vAxis.viewWindow.min = 123;
```

What you have written is incorrect for 2 reasons:

```
// this is bad
var options = { "vAxis.viewWindow" : [{min:"0"}] }
```

- this creates `options["vAxis.viewWindow"]` instead of `options["vAxis"]["viewWindow"]`
- this puts the value in an object and that object in an array. It would only be accessible like this: `options["vAxis.viewWindow"][0]["min"]`